# Maven replacer plugin - Output directory

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm using maven replacer plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/ with below configuration

```
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>api/**/*.java</include>
    </includes>
    <token>@Start.*?@End</token>
    <value></value>
    <regexFlags>
        <regexFlag>DOTALL</regexFlag>
    </regexFlags>
    <outputBasedir>publicapi</outputBasedir>
</configuration>
```

My project structure is api/src/main/java/...xxx.java. I want replacer plugin to generate files in this structure - publicapi/src/main/java/...xxx.java whereas with current configuration, plugin generates files like this -publicapi/**api**/src/main/java/...xxx.java

I don't want "api" directory in between. Is there any property available in this plugin which can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs it looks like outputDirectory](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/UsageGuide) is what you are searching for.

Comment: Yes, but if i uses outputDir/outputBasedir,it copies the source from parent directory (i.e api/src/main/java). I want to copy from src/main/java java only, don't want to include api while copying so that i can have my directory structure like publicapi/src/main/java rather having it like publicapi/api/src/main/java